# How does this "printing snail pattern" code work?

Tags: c, math

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int x;
    int y;
    for (x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
    {
        for (y = 1; y <= 5; y++)
        {
            i = 7848 + y * (-29412 + y * (23130 + y * (-6660 + y * 630)))
                    + x * (-16668 + y * (56629 + y * (-44066 + y * (12612 + y * -1186))))
                    + x * x * (11910 + y * (-35522 + y * (27183 + y * (-7696 + y * 717))))
                    + x * x * x * (-3420 + y * (9204 + y * (-6844 + y * (1908 + y * -176))))
                    + x * x * x * x * (330 + y * (-826 + y * (597 + y * (-164 + y * 15))));
            printf("%2d ", i/72);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
        1  2  3  4  5
        16 17 18 19 6
        15 24 25 20 7
        14 23 22 21 8
        13 12 11 10 9
```

What mathematic basis is behind this code?

EDIT: I know this code is useless and worthless, and can't be used in any other way. I am just curious about the mathematical basis behind this code...

Comment: Not really sure what the point of the question is, it looks like a bunch of math, thas all

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add an output!

Comment: Well... naively, you could *assume* that the value at each cell `(x, y)` is a polynomial in `x` and `y`, and then just solve for the coefficients.

Comment: Pft, it's just arithmetic, what's so complicated? IMO, someone didn't have anything to do, and decided to come up with something complicated (at first sight) that does nothing special and can be done in 3 rows, much, much, much more effective.

Comment: Well, I know this code is unnecessary, and can be coded in much more straightforward way, but I am asking someone to EXPLAIN how the above code works and the mathematics behind of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like someone's attempt to do something simple in a deliberately complicated way.

For each cell, it is calculating a polynomial in `x` and `y`. The value at each cell is a sum of terms `aijxiyj` for all 0<=i<=4 and 0<=j<=4.

To calculate the coefficients `aij` of the polynomial, you can substitute the values of `x` and `y` and the desired result for each cell. You'd get 25 linear equations with 25 variables, which can be solved with basic linear algebra.

Note that this method has nothing to do with the result being a spiral pattern: It could be used to print any result, the coefficients would just be different.

Comment: That is certainly a way to solve it, but unless the perpetrator took the trouble to group the terms after obtaining the required polynomial, I think the OP shows another way of solving this.

Comment: hm.. I am not sure whether the author grouped the terms intentionally to obfuscate the code, or maybe he used another way of solving this (which will group the terms as above in the process).

Comment: @Jacob: The terms are grouped in the OP, but that's just another way of writing the same thing. The coefficients will still be the same, and they are the important part.

Comment: @interjay: Yes of course ; my point was that the polynomial could have been derived using another method.

Answer (score 0):

The result of this code is as follow:

```
  1  2  3  4  5 
 16 17 18 19  6
 15 24 25 20  7 
 14 23 22 21  8 
 13 12 11 10  9
```

It looks indeed like numbers follow a snail pattern, but it does not work for square size greater, nor smaller. (change `5` to `7` or `3` gives bad results)

I guess it is just "pure luck", or more simply specific obfuscated code to print that pattern, but there is no mathematic basis behind that, as much as I can see.